# Sorting data bound datagrid in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf

Pretty much I want to accomplish what was asked about here:
[DataGrid - how to make Column sorting dynamic, to cater for when bound data changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852356/datagrid-how-to-make-column-sorting-dynamic-to-cater-for-when-bound-data-chang)

I found one version here:
http://wpf.codeplex.com/discussions/46939?ProjectName=wpf

What I really want is XAML version of manipulating CollectionViewSource 
Does anybody have sample on this?

Comment: I can write a simple behavior class that can be attached to a DataGrid and make semblance of xaml-code. Because there is no built-in functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think exact "solution" which is really workaround is [here](http://blog.nicktown.info/2008/12/10/using-a-collectionviewsource-to-display-a-sorted-entitycollection.aspx) and [more](http://blog.nicktown.info/2009/02/13/keeping-a-wpf-collectionviewsource-sorted.aspx).

What a pain :)